# How to show disjunction can be expressed as a conditional

Tags: symbolic-logic

How to show that formula "A ∨ B" can be constructed from A and B using only the conditional connective (→).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Are you asking for a proof that A v B is logically equivalent to ¬A -> B where -> is the material conditional?

Comment: not a homework forum...

Comment: By saying "how to show", are you asking for a formal proof, or just a simple illustration? A truth table would do the trick for the latter.

Answer (score 5):

We can use the following definition of "and": **A ∧ B ≡ ∀X [ (A → (B → X)) → X]**.

With it, we have:

> **A ∨ B ≡ ∀X [ (A → X) ∧ (B → X) → X]**.

---

We can also adopt another approach, taking into account that in [quantified propositional logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340195/why-is-quantified-propositional-logic-not-part-of-first-order-logic) we have that the [Flasum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)) constant can be defined as: **⊥ ≡ ∀X.X**.

With it we can define *negation*: **¬P ≡ (P → ⊥) ≡ P → ∀X.X**.

Thus, for classical logic, we can translate **P ∨ Q ≡ ¬P → Q ≡ (P → ∀X.X) → Q**.

Finally: **P ∧ Q ≡ ¬(P → ¬Q) ≡ (P → (Q → ∀X.X)) → ∀X.X**, that is basically the first formula above.

Comment: This is good!  I was going to comment that the problem with the conventional definition is that a replacement is also needed for the Law of Excluded Middle, but this definition gets around that.  It does, however, require a language with propositional quantifiers.

Comment: [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions#Defining_logical_operators) also defines it as a ∨ b ≡ ∀ c ((a → c) → (b → c) → c).

Comment: @user76284 - fine... (P → (Q → R)) is equiv to (P ∧ Q) → R)

Answer (score 0):

~AvB is equivalent to A->B.
So (~A)->B will be equivalent to AvB.

Answer (score -3):

> How to show disjunction can be expressed as a conditional

This is not possible. A disjunction cannot be expressed as a conditional.

This idea comes from the false notions about logic which are fundamental to mathematical logic. In particular, it is not true that ¬A ∨ B is equivalent to "If A, then B". The consequence is that "If ¬A, then B" is not equivalent to A ∨ B.

No expression containing only conditionals is equivalent to a conjunction.

This is why we have conditionals to begin with. If "If A, then B" was equivalent to ¬A ∨ B, we wouldn't need conditionals. We would say "A is false or B is true" instead of "If A, then B".

I would be interested if the downvoter could articulate what he objects to in my answer that justifies downvoting it, because every I here here is not only true, but common knowledge. You don't like the style?

Comment: Hello: This comment has been flagged because of its brevity. Could you expand a bit? This would help the Questioner and other users. Best - Geoffrey.

Comment: @Geoffrey Thomas  The answer posted by MathematicalPhysicist is shorter than mine and you didn't comment on it that it had been flagged for being too short.

Comment: I was only responding to a user's comment. flagged to the invigilators. If you want to leave you answer as it is, then I won't intervene further, but don't you think a little expansion would help the Questioner?